# Mouse pointer disappearing, can be fixed by closing laptop lid

Tags: windows-7, mouse

My mouse pointer frequently disappears on my laptop and the trackpoint stops working. The only fix that I'm aware of is to constantly close and re-open my laptop's lid until it decides to pop up. How can this be fixed?

Comment: How does it "stop working"? The pointer disappears? It stops reacting to movement? Or maybe you mean your touchpad, not mouse? Please ask about actual problems, not theoretical solutions you came up with.

Comment: The mouse pointer disappears and trackpad or trackpoint movement doesn't cause the mouse pointer to reappear.

Comment: That's better, I have edited your question. We still need more info, though. What laptop is it? Does pointer reappear first time you close and open the lid? Have you tried plugging in a mouse? Can you link the problem with anything? (eg. it happens only in one program or after some time of [not] using the mouse)

Comment: I see this problem on occasions when a virtual machine app has "captured" the mouse.  What apps are you running when you see the problem?

Comment: I haven't been able to trace it to any particular program.  It's a Thinkpad X220 Tablet.  The pointer doesn't appear the first time I open the lid; it's random every time I open the lid (including on startup).  I have to keep closing and reopening the lid until I get the mouse back.  I haven't tried plugging in a mouse.  (Sometimes I get the mouse pointer on a reboot, but sometimes not.  If not, the solution is just to keep closing and reopening the lid until I get the pointer.)

Comment: Was it working correctly before? Or maybe you've just bought that laptop? Does the touchscreen work when the issue appears?

Comment: It was working properly before.  The touchscreen still works (both touch and stylus).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to restart your mouse in windows 7 just plug in to other USB Port on your laptop, but it's not recommended to do, it's probably not enough power on your mouse to function properly or your mouse cable wire is not all connected. I usually change my mouse right away !  Or possibly your USB Port on your laptop is not tight enough to connect all pin's on your mouse, to fix that you just need to tighten up with a push-pin or little screwdriver, good luck !